# How to set segue from button made programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, button, segue

I create a button by code:

```
var button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton

button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)
button.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: "Action:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

self.view.addSubview(button)`
```

But now I want to do a segue, when button is tapped. Usually I do it with `@IBAction`, but now I made this button not in IB, but by code. So, how to set segue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Action:` method (which you should probably rename to `action:`), you can just call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` on the view controller that has the segue attached in the storyboard.

Comment: Like this? : `button.addTarget(self, action: performSegueWithIdentifier:"identifier",sender: self), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)`

Comment: No, you need to make a method called "func action( sender : AnyObject )" that has the line of code: self.performSegueWithIdentifier("identifier")

Answer (score 2):

give your segue directly from **current view controller** to **destination controller** and give it identifier And in Action call with identifier like this

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("your identifier", sender: self)
```